# Make another controllers view a partial (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

Have a post with comments. On post/show, when a user clicks the add comment button the server calls a javascript function that should add the new comment action as a partial:

```
render 'comments/new'

$("#newcomment").live("click",function() { $("#addcomment").load("<%= url_for :controller => 'comments', :action => 'new', :locals => {:parent_id => @post.parent_id} %>")

def new
  @comment = Comment.new( :parent_id => params[:parent_id] )
  render :partial => "form", :layout => false
end

new view:
render "form"  # form is the add comment form
```

The problem is that the local variables are not passed and I can't add the comment (it wont call create)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render *` never call an action in a controller, even `render :action => 'edit'`! It generates only the corresponding partial in every case. It may sometimes be confusing.

What you cand do to solve your probelm quickly is to call your partial via an ajax call.

In your views :

```
<div id="new_comment"></div>
```

In your controller :

```
render :update do
    replace 'news_comment', partial => 'comments/new'
end
```

Hope this help.

Comment: How do I call 'render :update' on a button click? Also do I place it in the show action or on it's own? Thanks.

Comment: it's better to put it in a controller of its own if you have already logic in it. You can do this for the button by adding {:remote => true} in the button tag.

Comment: Do you mean action of its own?

Comment: yeah, an action of its own or configure a respond_to option.