# Rails: Separate controller's method for partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, action, partial-views

Is it possible to create a separate controller's action (method) for specific partial view without involving AJAX or without doing as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941697/make-another-controllers-view-a-partial-rails-3)? In both these examples the views won't be partials in Rails notion.

Comment: Can u be a bit more specific with your question? maybe include a code snippet regarding what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial is a fancy name for a chunk of html that isn't a whole page.

You can render a partial in a controller action thus:

render :partial => "my_partial"

And the chunk will be rendered as contained in `_my_partial.html.erb` or whatever, and with no layout.

Inside an existing (ERB) template, you can use the same partial like this:

```
<%= render "my_partial" %>
```

Which will render the `_my_partial.html.erb` and insert it at that location.

Apart from that calling `render` on its own renders a view named after the action calling it, there is no special relationship between action names and view/view template names.  You can readily create an action that doesn't have a view template named after it and vice versa.  However if you create an action without a view you must call `render` at some point in the action and explicitly name the view that is to be rendered, or an error will result.

more details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: I know how to use partial view, but is there a way to assign separate controller's method to it?

Comment: @Paul, that is what Michal is saying, You could call any partial from any of your controller methods (as described above), But if you want something else, you might have to give more details..

Comment: The question being asked is, I believe, whether it's possible to render a partial that's tied to its own controller action. This answers the question of how to use partials, which is not the question being asked.